# How to code a simple d3.js network graph using DIVs as nodes

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, graph

I have a hard time understanding how D3 works. I'd just like to get a simple network graph (without animation nor “force” effects) using plain DIVs (containing formatted text) as nodes. No SVG is to be used for nodes.

The DIVs would be, for instance:

```
<div id="div1">One</div>
<div id="div2"><b>Two</b></div>
<div id="div3"><span style="color: red;">Three</span></div>
<div id="div4"><p class="someclass">Four</p></div>
```

The links between DIVs/nodes would be something like this (which is probably pseudo-JSON):

```
{
    "myDIVs":[
        {"name":"div1"},
        {"name":"div2"},
        {"name":"div3"},
        {"name":"div4"}
    ],
    "myLinks":[
        {"source":1,"target":2},
        {"source":1,"target":3},
        {"source":2,"target":1},
        {"source":4,"target":3}
    ]
}
```

What would be the right D3 code?

Comment: While what you want is possible, why do you want to work with `divs` and `html` here instead of `svg` nodes?  Network graphs have lines between nodes, without svg how are you going to draw these lines?

Comment: You're right: as long as nodes are plain old DIVs, I wouldn't mind the lines being SVG. (Just edited my question accordingly.) However I don't know if mixing DIV-nodes and SVG-lines is possible, at least using D3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to mix pre-build divs with d3's force layout and then SVG lines.  You would need to absolutely position the divs.  Here's a quick example, using your HTML and data structure.  *Note*, I changed your links to 0 based array indexes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    .node {
      fill: #ccc;
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    .link {
      stroke: #777;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1">One</div>
  <div id="div2"><b>Two</b></div>
  <div id="div3"><span style="color: red;">Three</span></div>
  <div id="div4">
    <p class="someclass">Four</p>
  </div>

  <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    var width = 400,
      height = 400;

    var data = {
      "myDIVs": [{
        "name": "div1"
      }, {
        "name": "div2"
      }, {
        "name": "div3"
      }, {
        "name": "div4"
      }],
      "myLinks": [{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1
      }, {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2
      }, {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 0
      }, {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 2
      }]
    };

    var nodes = data.myDIVs,
      links = data.myLinks;

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([width, height])
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .linkDistance(250)
      .charge(-50);

    var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
      .data(links)
      .enter().append('line')
      .attr('class', 'link');

    var node = d3.selectAll('div')
      .data(nodes)
      .each(function(d) {
        var self = d3.select('#' + d.name);
        self.style("position", "absolute");
      });

    force.on('end', function() {
      node
        .style('left', function(d) {
          return d.x + "px";
        })
        .style('top', function(d) {
          return d.y + "px";
        });

      link.attr('x1', function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr('y1', function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr('x2', function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr('y2', function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });
    });
    
    force.start();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) force.tick();
    force.stop();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to completely disable "force" animations, so as the graph shows up in its final state? Also, is there a way to prevent the DIVs from overlapping?

Comment: @JYF, yes, see code changes above.  I would suggest, though, that if you want to control the position of the nodes, that a force layout is not the best layout choice.  Perhaps a [cluster layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout) is more suitable.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. If I understand well, dendograms produced by the cluster layout do not allow some random element in the hierarchy to be linked to another random element (which is something I'd like to achieve). I also like the random positions of the DIVs generated by your code. There must be a way to prevent overlapping, or even to set a minimum distance between DIVs, but I suppose those refinements are buried in the D3 documentation…?